# How do I leave a clan

Tags: starcraft-2

How do I leave a clan in StarCraft 2? I have tried / chat commands and right click profiles, maybe I just cant find the right button or the right word to use when leaving.

Answer (score 4):

You have to click the actual groups button (the button to the right of your friends list). This is where you leave a clan or group my right clicking it in this menu and clicking “leave clan/group”